# Multi-threading C# and Merge SQL Query - SqlException - Deadlock

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, ado.net

I have multi-threaded application each thread execute a merge stored procedure. I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction (Process ID 104) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

Solutions attempted:

- Using transaction in merge stored procedure but failed get success getting same error as above.

My stored procedure is here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MergeEngComputerFiles]
    @ComputerId BIGINT,
    @Files [dbo].[EngComputerFileTableType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE @cId BIGINT;
    DECLARE @fId BIGINT;
    DECLARE @fPath NVARCHAR(1000);

    SELECT TOP (1)
        @cId = [ComputerId],
        @fId = [FolderId],
        @fPath = [FilePath]
    FROM
        @Files;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT <= 0 
        RETURN;

    MERGE [dbo].[EngComputerFile] AS [Target]
    USING @Files AS [Source] ON [Source].ComputerId = [Target].[ComputerId]
                             AND [Source].[FolderId] = [Target].[FolderId] 
                             AND [Source].[FilePath] = [Target].[FilePath] 
                             AND [Source].[FileName] = [Target].[FileName]

    -- When Matched Update Record 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE 
            SET [Target].[LastWriteTimeUtc] = [Source].[LastWriteTimeUtc],
                [Target].[ReadOnly] = [Source].[ReadOnly]

    -- When Not Matched Insert Record
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT (ComputerId, FolderId, FilePath, 
                FileName, Size,
                LastWriteTimeUtc, ReadOnly) 
        VALUES ([Source].ComputerId, [Source].FolderId, [Source].FilePath,
                [Source].FileName, [Source].Size,
                [Source].LastWriteTimeUtc, [Source].ReadOnly) 

    --For Delete
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
             AND [Target].[ComputerId] = @cId 
             AND [Target].[FolderId] = @fId 
             AND [Target].[FilePath] = @fPath
        THEN 
            DELETE;

    UPDATE [Inbox].[dbo].[EngComputer]
    SET [LastScanTimeStampUtc] = SYSUTCDATETIME()
    WHERE [ComputerId] = @cId;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
GO
```

C# code:

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper();
string sqlQuery = "MergeEngComputerFiles";

try
{   
    databaseHelper.Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString();
            
   databaseHelper.CreateDBObjects(databaseHelper.Connectionstring, DatabaseHelper.Providers.SqlServer);

   using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
   {
       dt.Columns.Add("ComputerId", typeof(int));
       dt.Columns.Add("FolderId", typeof(int));
       dt.Columns.Add("FilePath", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(long));
       dt.Columns.Add("LastWriteTimeUtc", typeof(DateTime));
       dt.Columns.Add("ReadOnly", typeof(bool));
       dt.Columns.Add("LastWriteCacheTimeUtc", typeof(DateTime));

       foreach (var item in listFileInformation)
       {
           if (item != null)
           {
               dt.Rows.Add(item.ComputerId, item.FolderId,
                           item.FilePath, item.FileName, item.Size,
                           item.LastWriteUTC, item.ReadOnly,
                           item.LastWriteCacheTimeUTC);
           }
       }

       databaseHelper.AddParameter("@ComputerId", computerId);

       SqlParameter tableTypeParam = new SqlParameter("@Files", SqlDbType.Structured)
                {
                    TypeName = "dbo.EngComputerFileTableType",
                    Value = dt
                };

       databaseHelper.AddParameter(tableTypeParam);

       databaseHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlQuery, 
                                      System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, 
                                      System.Data.ConnectionState.Open);

       // closing  of connection is done in Execute non query
   }
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlException)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(sqlException.Message);
    Debug.WriteLine(sqlException.StackTrace);
    Logger.Error($"{sqlQuery} stored procedure failed.", sqlException);
}
finally
{
    if (databaseHelper != null)
    {
        databaseHelper.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating a new connection in each one of your spawned threads or sharing a connection?

Comment: @Ross Bush , yes new connection with every threads. I have add in question ado.net c# connection code.

Comment: READ UNCOMMITTED - Will hold less resources/locks but could also allow for dirty, nonrepeatable and phantom reads. Make sure you are ok with that on busy parts of the system. There is no magic cure to avoid deadlocks, below is an long article, but if you scan to the deadlock section there is a boatload of information on deadlock detection and avoidance. -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15. Another thing you may consider is partitioning your threading to isolate concurrent  access, if possible

Comment: @RossBush , I appreciate your response however I knew the complication of avoiding the ACID principles. My requirement is to insert concurrent entries in table. I don't want to read from that table and so dirty read wont be the problem.